# plotly plotly how to change the legend

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

how to change the legend, in particular the underscore?

I have a dataframe (df):

| date | humidity_min | humidity_mean | humidity_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 0.21 | 0.57 | 1 |
| 2022-02-01 | 0.10 | 0.56 | 1 |
| 2022-03-01 | 0.24 | 0.71 | 1 |

....

I have tried:

```
labels = {'date':'Date', 
          'temperature_min':'Temperature min', 
          'temperature_mean':'Temperature mean',
          'temperature_max':'Temperature max',
          }

# Temperature
fig = px.line(df, x='date', y=['temperature_min', 'temperature_mean', 'temperature_max'], 
              title = 'Temperature',
              color_discrete_sequence=['red', 'green', 'blue'],
              labels=labels,
              )
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(tickformat="%B-%Y"), 
                  template = "plotly_dark",
                  )
fig.show()
```

I get:

[image]

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Try this: `labels = {'temperature_min':'Temperature min','temperature_mean':'Temperature mean','temperature_max':'Temperature max'};for i in [labels[d] for d in labels]:   fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(name=i))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fig.update_trace`, you can have `fig.for_each_trace()` to update the mode and name of the legend for each trace. Replace underscores with white spaces, for example,

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda trace:trace.update(mode = 'markers+lines', name = trace.name.replace('_',' ')))
```

If you want more flexibility, you can have

```
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
legend_name = ['name1','name2','name3'] 
for ind, d in enumerate(fig.data):
    d.name = legend_name[ind]
```